# EJB EntityManager Exception

Tags: jpa, ejb, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.0

I have the following defined in persistence

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/testDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>test.entity.Employees</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="OC4J"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.target-database" value="Oracle"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.logging.parameters" value="TRUE"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Java code snippet where I am invoking EntityManager, I am getting exception.
How can I solve the issue?

With non-jta data source I am able to retrieve data using REST and CriteriaBuilder does work without any glitch

Code snippet

```
@Stateless(name="SessionEJB2")
@Path("/mypath")
public class SessionEJB2Bean implements SessionEJB2{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="test")
    private EntityManager em;
    .......
    .......

    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder(); // getting excpetion
```

Exception stack

```
The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:734)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:391)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:908)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:458)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.serveOneRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:226)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:127)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:116)
    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260)
    at com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:303)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: It seems that the EntityManager is not injected. One case would be if persistence.xml is on the wrong path. Where have you placed it? By the way in order your question to be complete please provide us the exception stack trace (or at least the part with the NullPointerException).

Comment: Can you show a stack trace of the failure?  I'm interested in how SessionEJB2Bean is called; is it being invoked by the JAX-RS container?  If so, it looks like the JAX-RS container is not integrating with the EJB container.  Are you using an application server that has integrated JAX-RS with EJB, or are you just including a JAX-RS library in your application?

Comment: @bkail I have included exception stack trace. I am including JAX-RS library in my application.

Comment: By default, JAX-RS does not support integration, and since you included a JAX-RS library in your application, the `@Stateless` will not do anything.  Perhaps your best option is to declare the EntityManager in web.xml (or as a class-level annotation on some listener), and then use JNDI to look it up.

Comment: @bkail Something similar to [this](http://yatb.giacomodrago.com/en/post/7/tutorial-restful-web-service-ejb-hibernate-jpa-jboss.html) approach. If not could you provide an example? Thanks

Comment: @MikeArgyriou I have added exception stack trace. persistence.xml is in fact in correct location.

Comment: @bkail: If you mean that you cannot integrate JAX-RS with EJB you are correct but until Java EE 6. Since Java EE 7 they can be combined. For more info see this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jaxrs20-1929352.html. This way you can easily provide thread-safety to your REST resources.

Comment: @user75ponic: By the way aligned with my previous comment do you use Java EE 7?

Comment: @MikeArgyriou No I am not using Java EE 7, my Java EE version is in fact 4.

Comment: Java EE 4 (since 2003)? I think that annotations are supported since Java EE 5 (since 2006). Moreover JPA is included in Java EE since Java EE 5. Therefore @PersistenceContext won't work with Java EE 4. For more info check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE_version_history#J2EE_1.4_.28November_11.2C_2003.29

Comment: @MikeArgyriou I apologize, my version is Java EE 5

Comment: Then JAX-RS will not work (@Path) since it is supported since Java EE 6. This is confirmed by the multiple appearances of "jersey" in exception stack. By the way the exception stack trace that you have enlisted doesn't show that the exception happens where you say: "CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();"

Comment: @MikeArgyriou With non-jta data source I am able to retrieve data using REST and CriteriaBuilder does work without any glitch.

Comment: @user75ponic: Thank you for this extra info. Please update your post with it so that the question is complete.

Comment: @MikeArgyriou I did that.

Comment: @bkail I have tried using class-level annotation or Container Managed EntityManager however I am still getting nullpointer exception. Could you have a look as I have posted another question regarding this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606442/nullpointerexception-incontainer-managed-entitymanager

Comment: @user75ponic I don't believe it's possible to do what you're trying to do.  I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to use EE injection annotations in a JAX-RS class when you have embedded a JAX-RS library in your application.  It is only possible if you are using JAX-RS from an application server that has integrated the JAX-RS container with EJB, CDI, or managed bean.

In order to use container-managed JPA when embedding a JAX-RS library in your application, you must declare the JPA resource in the WAR (either web.xml or as a class-level annotation on a listener, filter, or some other servlet in the application), and then use JNDI to access the container-managed JPA resource.  Note, your application server must support container-managed JPA or else this approach won't work either, and you'll need to use application-managed JPA.