# NameNotFoundException in Container Managed EntityManager

Tags: jpa, ejb, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.0, jndi

I am trying to use Container Managed EntityManager, however I am getting NameNotFoundException. I have tried adding entries in web.xml but in vain.

```
@Stateless
@Path("/mypath")
public class EmployeeService {

    @EJB
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

    @GET
    @Path("/myresults")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Employee getValues() {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        try  {
            emp = employeeDAO.getEmployees(); // exception here
        } catch (Exception ex)  {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return emp;
    }
```

EmployeeDAO code snippet

```
public class EmployeeDAO {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "test-ejb", name = "persistence/em")

    public Employee getEmployees() throws NamingException {
        int empNo = 342;
        Context context = new InitialContext();
        context.lookup("java:comp/env");
        EntityManager em = (EntityManager)context.lookup("persistence/em");
        return em.find(Employee.class, empNo);
    }
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="test-ejb" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/testDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>test.entity.Employees</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="OC4J"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.target-database" value="Oracle"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.logging.parameters" value="TRUE"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Exception stack

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: persistence/em not found
>       at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.rmi.RMIServerContext.lookup(RMIServerContext.java:207)
>       at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.ApplicationContext.unprivileged_lookup(ApplicationContext.java:256)
>       at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.ApplicationContext.lookup(ApplicationContext.java:196)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
>       at test.dao.EmployeeDAO.getValues(EmployeeDAO.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
>       at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:734)
>       at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:391)
>       at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:908)
>       at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:458)
>       at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.serveOneRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:226)
>       at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:127)
>       at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:116)
>       at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260)
>       at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:303)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

**Update 1**

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class EmployeeDAO {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "test-ejb", name = "persistence/em")

    public Employee getEmployees() throws NamingException {
        int empNo = 342;
        Context context = new InitialContext();
        context.lookup("java:comp/env");
        EntityManager em = (EntityManager)context.lookup("persistence/em");
        return em.find(Employee.class, empNo);
    }
```

Exception

> javax.ejb.EJBException: Setter injection being applied to non-setter method: getValues; nested exception is: java.lang.InstantiationException: Setter injection being applied to non-setter method: getValues

Full stack

> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: Setter injection being applied to non-setter method: getValues
>       at com.evermind.server.deployment.J2EEContextAnnotationParser.validateInjectionSetter(J2EEContextAnnotationParser.java:713)
>       at com.evermind.server.deployment.J2EEContextAnnotationParser.createInjectionTarget(J2EEContextAnnotationParser.java:729)
>       at com.evermind.server.deployment.J2EEContextAnnotationParser.parseInjectedMethod(J2EEContextAnnotationParser.java:378)
>       at com.evermind.server.ejb.deployment.BeanDescriptorAnnotationParser.parseInjectedMethodAndCallbacks(BeanDescriptorAnnotationParser.java:276)
>       at com.evermind.server.ejb.deployment.SessionBeanDescriptorAnnotationParser.parseInjectedMethodAndCallbacks(SessionBeanDescriptorAnnotationParser.java:95)
>       at com.evermind.server.ejb.deployment.BeanDescriptorAnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(BeanDescriptorAnnotationParser.java:77)
>       at com.evermind.server.ejb.deployment.BeanDescriptorAnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(BeanDescriptorAnnotationParser.java:48)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at com.evermind.server.ejb.BeanAnnotationListener.parseAnnotatedClass(BeanAnnotationListener.java:45)

Comment: Please add the full exception report

Comment: @ZaheerKhorajiya I have included exception trace.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
public class EmployeeDAO {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "test-ejb", name = "persistence/em")
...
```

to:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "test-ejb", name = "persistence/em")
@Stateless
public class EmployeeDAO {
...
```

Comment: I have tried as you have suggested, however I am getting `NullPointerException` at `emp = employeeDAO.getEmployees();`

Answer (score 1):

EmployeeDAO must be a container-managed class (listener, filter, servlet, EJB, managed bean, CDI managed bean, etc.), not a POJO.  The JPA container will only search for JPA annotations on container-managed classes, not on POJOs.

Your options are:

1. Change EmployeeDAO to be a container-managed class.  For example, if your application server supports EJBs, then add the `@Stateless` annotation to the class.
2. Move the `@PersistenceContext` annotation to a container-managed class.  For example, if you have an existing listener, filter, or servlet, move the annotation to that class.
3. Add `<persistence-context-ref>` to web.xml.

Note, your application server must support container-managed JPA for any of these approaches to work.

Comment: I have done as suggested by you, however when I added @Stateless to EmployeeDAO, I am getting `javax.ejb.EJBException: Setter injection being applied to non-setter method:` Full error stack trace added in my question in Update 1 section. Thanks

Comment: @user75ponic You're missing (or deleted?) the em field.  Try `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "test-ejb", name = "persistence/em") private EntityManager em;`

Comment: I have added `private EntityManager em;` as yu have suggested, this resulted in `NameNotFoundException`

Comment: I have found another exception while debugging which is `com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.ejb.exception.DeploymentException: [current-workspace-app:ejbsession] - Unknown persistence unit with name "test-ejb".
 at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) `

Comment: Is your persistence.xml in the `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/` folder of the WAR?  If yes, then I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: `persistence.xml` is in fact under `META-INF/` and at the time of development using Jdeveloper, WAR is not generated. Thanks